# $\beta(s) = \int_0^s B(u)\,du$ is a unit speed curve

Tags: integration, geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I'm teaching myself in this [differential geometry book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521133114), so please have some patience with me if I ask something obvious.

Let $\alpha(s)$ be a unit speed curve with domain $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ and with $k_\alpha>0$ and $\tau_\alpha>0$. Let:

$$\beta(s) = \int_0^s B(u)\,du$$

$(1)$ Prove that $\beta(s)$ is a unit speed curve

$(2)$ Show that the Frenet-Serret apparatus for $\beta(s)$ is $[k_\beta,\tau_\beta,\overline{T},\overline{N},\overline{B}]$ where $k_\beta = \tau_\alpha, \tau_\beta=k_\alpha,\overline{N}=-N$ and $\overline{B} = T$, and $[k_\alpha,\tau_\alpha,T,N,B]$ is the Frenet-Serret apparatus for $\alpha(s)$/

As I understood about unit speed curve from the book, I just have to find a parametrization and say that it's lenght is $1$. Or do I have to prove that this parametrization has lenght $1$? Of even better: aren't all functions independent of reparametrization?

for $(2)$, I know that the Frenet-Serret apparatus is represented by $[k_\alpha,\tau_\alpha,T,N,B]$ as the book says. However I din't find what the top bar means in each of these symbols. I know that $k$ is the curvature, $\tau$ is the torsion, but what are the capital letters with overline? I truly didn't understand this question :(

Comment: For (1), what happens when you differentiate $\beta$?

Comment: Every curve can be reparameterised to have unit speed, but you should show that \beta is already unit speed, ie \beta'(s) has magnitude 1.

Comment: @Travis I get $\beta(u)$ since its the derivative of an integral. But how does it proves that its lenght is $1$?

Comment: The F.T.C. should give you $\beta'(s) = {\bf B}(s)$, but $\bf B$ is the binormal vector, which has unit length by construction.

Comment: @Travis why $B$ is a binormal vector? Sorry, I'm too dumb but I'm trying to self teach

Comment: I assume that's what's meant by $\bf B$. (After all, ${\bf B}(s)$ has to be a unit vector field along $\alpha$ in order for (1) to be true in the first place.) In fact, later you write, "...is represented by $[\cdots, T, N, {\bf B}]$" (emphasis mine).